# Soft delete in Sails/Waterline

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, soft-delete

Trying to delete a user model using:

```
//Hard Delete    
User.destroy({id:userId}, function(err, res){  
  //Hard Delete
})
```

I need to do a soft delete on User model and currently setting a flag isDeleted to true on delete and updating document:

```
updateUser.isDeleted = true;
User.update({id:userId}, updateUser, function(err, res){
  Update project
})
```

and while fetching documents I am doing a check If isDeleted - true or not.
Is there any In-built feature provided by Sails or Waterline which I can configure to perform a soft delete and avoid updating and then fetching based on isDeleted flag?

Comment: you can do this easy using this pull request https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/pull/525 if they get it implemented.

Answer (score 1):

you can use beforeFind() life cycle function for filter of soft deleted records

model: parrot,js

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        // e.g., "Polly"
        name: {
            type: 'string'
        },

        // e.g., 3.26
        wingspan: {
            type: 'float',
            required: true
        },

        // e.g., "cm"
        wingspanUnits: {
            type: 'string',
            enum: ['cm', 'in', 'm', 'mm'],
            defaultsTo: 'cm'
        },

        // e.g., [{...}, {...}, ...]
        knownDialects: {
          collection: 'Dialect'
        },

        isDeleted:{
            type:'boolean'
        }
    },

    beforeFind: function(values, cb) {
        values.isDeleted = false;
        cb();
    }
}
```

ParrotController.js

```
module.exports = {

    // getting default parrots isDeleted = true
    list: function (req, res) {

        Parrot
        .find()
        .exec(function(err, parrots) {
            if(err) return res.send({ flag:false, data:[], message:"Error." });

            if(parrots && parrots.length){
                return res.send({ flag:true, data:parrots, message:"Success." });
            }
            else{
                return res.send({ flag:false, data:[], message:"Parrot list is empty." });
            }

        });

    }
};
```

Comment: This is not officialy implemented by sails, rigth? It is a feature made in a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

There is no soft-delete feature built into sails, and I doubt there will be.

Here's a challenge: why not write your own? [Waterline supports class methods](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/models/instance-class-methods.md)! Of course you would have to do it for each model or create a service... which might be even more effective.