# Soft delete in sails.js

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I'm trying to implement soft delete on a model in a sails.js project by I override the delete action in the respective controller to just update a boolean attribute called isDeleted.

The problem I'm facing is that, I need to override the find action for the respective controller so that it'll ignore the "deleted" records but I need to keep the rest of the original functionality. To do this I'm simply copying the code of the original find action into the override, but it depends on the actionUtil module, and, when doing the require for that module, no matter how I change the route it never manages to find the module.

So, this is what my controller looks like:

```
var actionUtil = require('/sails/lib/hooks/blueprints/actionUtil'),
_ = require('lodash');

module.exports = {

find: function(req, res){

    // Look up the model
    var Model = actionUtil.parseModel(req);

    if ( actionUtil.parsePk(req) ) {
        return require('./findOne')(req,res);
    }

    // Lookup for records that match the specified criteria
    var query = Model.find()
    .where( actionUtil.parseCriteria(req) )
    .limit( actionUtil.parseLimit(req) )
    .skip( actionUtil.parseSkip(req) )
    .sort( actionUtil.parseSort(req) );

    // TODO: .populateEach(req.options);
    query = actionUtil.populateEach(query, req);

    query.exec(function found(err, matchingRecords) {
        if (err) return res.serverError(err);

        // Only `.watch()` for new instances of the model if
        // `autoWatch` is enabled.
        if (req._sails.hooks.pubsub && req.isSocket) {
            Model.subscribe(req, matchingRecords);

            if (req.options.autoWatch)
                { Model.watch(req); }

            // Also subscribe to instances of all associated models
            _.each(matchingRecords, function (record) {
                actionUtil.subscribeDeep(req, record);
            });
        }

        res.ok(matchingRecords);
    });

},//End .find

destroy: function(req,res){   

    console.log("Parametro: " + req.param('id') );
    Vendedor.update({ id_vendedor: req.param('id') }, { isDeleted: true })
    .exec(function (err, goal) 
    {
        if (err)
            return res.status(400).json(err);        

        return res.json(goal[0]);
    });

}
};
```

But, when starting the server I get an error, saying that the module actionUtil couldn't be found. Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: refer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27243034/soft-delete-in-sails-waterline/40438436#40438436

Comment: @ArjunKava I had already seen that post, but like I said, I need to keep the original functionality.